# Why NLA editor run only the top action strip

Tags: animation, nla-editor, dopesheet, makehuman

I get an error when I try to create a walk cycle using two action strip. The first is walk cycle in place and the second moving cycle from point A to point b. I could not understand why the NLA run only the top action ? 
When I put the walk cycle as the top, the person walks in place and when I put the moving cycle at the top the person moves from A to B without any motion walking!!!
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: This should work: http://pasteall.org/blend/34671 could you upload your .blend have you changed other properties then repeat for the walkcycle? Or accidentally keyframed same bones in both actions?

Comment: @stacker, I uploaded my file

Comment: @stacker, What is the error?

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: @stacker http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34672

Answer (score 1):

You keyframed all bones in the movement action:

[image]

When you delete everything but the first (master) then it would work as expected.

The reason why couldn't see this is the checked show_only_errors option:

[image]

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/34686)

Comment: So, Why i should keyframe only the master when I move a person or it is principle of blender?

Comment: @startingBlender because this is how it works, otherwise the instruction are contradictory and the last one wins. Like go left, no go right.

Comment: @startingBlender uploaded the fixed .blend.

Comment: I have had an amazing problem about IK and FK mode. Snap is used to copy the animation from IK to FK or from FK to IK. So, normally, When i do an animation using IK and FK mode, I can finally run it in each mode without loss for any motion. but in http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34672, I remark that when i run it in IK mode for all bones, the hands did not move. What is the problem?

Comment: @startingBlender You should post this as another question.

Comment: I have posted it here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/snap-fk-ik-does-not-copy-the-motion